# Publishing unmodifiable view to an internal map

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading B. Goetz Java Concurrency In Practice and now I'm at the section about delegating thread safety. He provided the following example:

```
@Immutable
public class Point{
    public final int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

@ThreadSafe
public class DelegatingVehicleTracker {

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Point> locations;
    private final Map<String, Point> unmodifiableMap;

    public DelegatingVehicleTracker(Map<String, Point> points){
        locations = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Point>(points);
        unomdifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(locations);
    }

    public Map<String, Point> getLocations(){
        return unmodifiableMap;
    }

    public Point getLocation(String id){
        return locations.get(id);
    }

    public void setLocation(String id, int x, int y){
        if(locations.replace(id, new Point(x, y)) == null)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid vehicle id: " + id);
    }

}
```

He said that

> if thread *A* calls getLocations and thread *B* later modifies the
>   locations of some of the point, those changes are reflected in the
>   `Map` returned to thread *A*. As we remarked earlier, this can be a
>   benefit (more up-to-date data) or a liability (potentially
>   inconsistent view of the fleet), depending on your requirement.

I didn't understand the drawback. Why is it possible for the view of the fleet to become inconsistent. All objects are immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects are *not* immutable: `locations` is not, and so neither is `unmodifiableMap`.

The problem is potentially less tricky than you're looking for. Since `locations` is thread safe, and `unmodifiableMap` doesn't have any state other than an (immutable) reference to `locations`, there are no weird memory visibility issues.

The weirdness is that to a consumer of this class, `getLocation` looks like it can "magically" change values from any given thread. In other words, if a thread does this:

```
Point p1 = tracker.getLocation("vehicle1");
Point p2 = tracker.getLocation("vehicle1");
assert p1.equals(p2);
```

... then the writer of that code may be surprised that it ever fails. After all, I just got the point twice for the same vehicle, and didn't call `setLocation` between them — so how could the location have changed? The answer, of course, is that some *other* thread called `setLocation`, and I saw that change happen between the two calls to `getLocation`.

The example above is obviously a bit silly, but less silly examples aren't hard to imagine. For instance, let's say your application wants to do a snapshot of the fleet, and it assumes that two trucks can't be at the same point at the same time. This is a reasonable assumption in the physical world, but it's not one your application can make, because one truck may have moved into another truck's location between calls to `getLocation`:

```
Thread1 (taking a snapshot)             Thread2 (updating locations)
                                        setLocation("truckA", 10, 10);
                                        setLocation("truckB", 20, 20);
p1 = getLocation("truckA") // (10, 10)
                                        setLocation("truckA", 5, 10);
                                        setLocation("truckB", 10, 10);
p2 = getLocation("truckB") // (10, 10)
assert !p1.equals(p2);     // fails
```

As the blurb mentions, this isn't inherently bad; it all depends on your application's needs and expectations.

Comment: Your "silly" example is actually very clear, thanks much.